# Return string in a array without object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

This is how I am getting:

```
 "skills":[
                  {
                     "cityname":"Kaduna North"
                  }
               ]
```

How I want is:

```
"skills":["Kaduna North"]
```

is that possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, but which one of the three databases are you actually using, how are you getting that result etc. Please explain more clearly what you want to do

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am using SQL server 2017 and there is provision to create the JSON

Comment: okay thanks @DaleK will do that

Comment: Then please correct you tags, MySQL is not SQL Server, nor is PostgreSQL

Comment: @SandeepSingh Does the `skills` JSON array always have a single item?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsonInfo=N'{
            "skills": [{
                        "cityname": "Kaduna North"
                       }]
            }'

;

SELECT 
     concat('"skills":["',
            JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.skills[0].cityname')
             ,'"]'
     )
;
```

Or use the below:

```
 SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(
         concat('["',
               JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo,'$.skills[0].cityname')
               ,'"]'
    ) ) as skills
 FOR JSON PATH
```